# What is the best - the most robust interactive platform for running the Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

In the past, i.e., in late 2019, I have made my short workshop using [Binder](https://mybinder.org/) and its interactive **Jupyter Notebooks**. It was mostly successful, with one major crash and with some specific, "local" glitches for a few of the students.

I would appreciate it very much if you could share your experiences: what is the best - the most robust interactive platform for running the **Jupyter Notebooks**? My old **Binders** were all in **Python**, but I would be keen to have a few in **R** as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use both R or Python in Google colab

Although Python is the default language, there is an option to use R as well.

to run R you can use this link https://colab.research.google.com/#create=true&language=r

Furthermore, once the notebook is created, it saved in your one drive, and you can share the link to the script as you would share any file in google drive.

To Change the language from R to python, just click on Runtime --> Runtime type --> select the desired language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google has an stable implementation. But it supports only Python.

https://colab.research.google.com/